# Custom controller and Entity mapping

Tags: dxa

We have created a Custom "Generic module" in DXA Java code. We have created the following additional items:

1) Entity class "HTMLForm" under the custom package "com.kc.webapp.common.api.model.entity"

2) Module initializer class under the custom package "com.kc.webapp.main.modules.generic" with the code

```
    viewModelRegistry.registerViewEntityClass("Generic:HTMLForm", HTMLForm.class);
```

3) Created a View JSP file "HTMLForm" in location "/web-inf/view/generic/entity/"

4) A Controller class to display the content.

We are getting this error by putting "Generic:Generic" value in "Controller Name" field of the "MVC metadata" of Component Template.

```
ERROR c.s.w.m.c.core.MainController - Exception while processing request for: /system/mvc/Generic/Generic/Entity/Main/349
com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.exception.BadRequestException: Request to unknown action: /system/mvc/Generic/Generic/Entity/Main/349
```

and if that field is blank then we are getting full page according to the view but without any data.

Can we use Core Controllers to get the data of any custom entity?

What are the steps for mapping the custom controller with the entity?